# Python virtual environment creation error(Permission Error 13)

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

I know this has been asked several times; however I'm yet to see a topic using the Windows (Windows 10, FYI) Command console [and actually being resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46222367/errno-13-permission-denied-python-as-a-windows-service)

So, the problem starts when I try to create a new virtual environment from the CMD in a certain folder which is called **web_scraper**, I have successfully installed the latest version of `pip` and I have Python 3.6.1; also, I've created another virtual environment before and even installed Flask in it, and yes, also did a successful mini-try in the localhost.

When I type this into the CMD to create a new venv, this happens:

```
C:\Users\Nilor2000\Desktop\Proyectos\web_scraper>virtualenv venv

...[lots of yadayada that all comes down to this:]

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Nilor2000\\Desktop\\Proyectos\\web_scraper\\venv\\lib\\os.py'
```

**Now, this is the *interesting* part**, since I use PyCharm to code, it automatically creates a `venv` folder for every new project, which contains everything for a virtual environment, so I did a separate test folder, copied the `venv` folder which comes by default and it was then that I had to just **`activate`** it, **not** create it. And it was **there** with that "default" `venv` folder that I could run the localhost test and install Flask.

So, my final question is: What is wrong with my system that won't allow me to create a new `virtual environment`?

- I have the rights of admin
- Already installed everything I need to create and run `venv`s
- Yes, I already ran the CMD as admin, didn't work

Please, someone help, I don't want to copy and paste the same `venv` folder for every project :(

/-/-/-/-/-/-/-//-/-/-/-/-/-/-//-/-/-/-/-/-/-//-/-/-/-/-/-/-//-/-/-/-/-/-/-//-/-/-/-/-/-/-//-/-/-/-/-/-/-//-/-/-/-/-/-/-//-/-/-/-/-/-/-/

**EDIT**

So, if somebody is facing a similar problem and can't create a new `virtualenv` **but** has `pip` and the `virtualenv` resource installed, you can download it separately.

I've created a GitHub repository for that particular case, [It's this one](https://github.com/CommieTaco/venv-for-py3.6)

If you decide to use it, please let me know if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message. I created the virtualenv from a batch script. Running it gave me the [Errno 13] message.

I noticed that the virtualenv was already created so the new one was denied.